# Summing unique combination values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to group and sum unique combination of nodes in an XML.

```
<root>
    <row>
        <field1>720</field1>
        <field2>8900</field2>
        <field3>100</field3>        
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>720</field1>
        <field2>99998</field2>        
        <field3>120</field3>       
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>720</field1>
        <field2>8900</field2>
        <field3>130</field3>        
    </row>
    <row>
        <field1>720</field1>
        <field2>12403</field2>
        <field3>130</field3>        
    </row>
</root>
```

So, for every unique combination of field1 and field2, I need to produce the sum of field3

I understand group-by is something that can be used, but not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how you can use [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) and `group-by` the values of the `field1` and `field2` elements for each row. For each group, produce the `sum()` of the `field3` elements and `@key` to demonstrate what the grouping-key values are:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <summary>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/root/row" 
                                group-by="string-join((field1,field2),'-')">
                <sum key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/field3)" />
                </sum>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </summary>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run against the sample data, it produces the following output:

```
<summary>
   <sum key="720-8900">230</sum>
   <sum key="720-99998">120</sum>
   <sum key="720-12403">130</sum>
</summary>
```